# ViewController-Xib calling randomly

Tags: random, uiviewcontroller, ios7, xib

In my App,i want to call xib's randomly when the next button is clicked each time.
Is it possible to do with arc4random() method ? 
Please share your ideas.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: Ok.In my first viewController i have an UIslider. For eg when the slider value is one and the user clicking next button,it should go to the secondview controller,and again user clicking the back button it goes to the firstview controller,now the slider value is same one and user clicking the next button,it should go to some other controller.Clear ?

Comment: means every time on button click you want to change push view controller

Comment: yes .exactly.how to do that ?

Comment: You are using storyboard or xib?

Comment: am using xib .is it possible to do with storyboard ???

Comment: both have the same logic man

Comment: How many views you have for push from firstview controller using button click

Comment: ok... first of all declare any int value in AppDelegate file

Comment: check this http://pastie.org/8659319

Comment: thanks.Working like a charm.

Comment: ok bro... feels good after hearing that it's working for you

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:arc4random_uniform(controllers.count) animated:YES];   is this the right way to call view controllers randomly ?

Comment: yes you can also do that but you have to pass view controller at pushviewcontroller